# Website Editor control for WYSIWYG/regions

Tags: wysiwyg

For lack of a better title, let me try to explain further:

I'm looking for a control that will allow me to have a library of "page elements" (such as a list of employees, or a photo gallery, or a contact form, etc) that could be dragged onto the page canvas.

The page canvas could have pre-set regions/boxes where these items could be drug into, preventing the user from screwing up the pages layout.

I'm looking for any pre-built commercial (or open-source with commercial use allowed) tools available like this.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off looking for a content management system that supports this as a feature, rather than something that has this as its Unique Selling Point. So for example, Blogger and Wordpress do, although they are mainly for blogs.

A quick search shows that Joomla does: http://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/959-drag-n-drop-is-here.html.